# Se puede utilizar el UNION y el JOIN en un solo query?

Tags: sql

Se puede utilizar UNION y JOIN tengo un query donde se usa dos `select` de la cual esas dos estan utilizando UNION y luego tengo otro select que quiero unir con un join

Comment: En preguntas de SQL, es una buena idea publicar una muestra de los datos que tienes de entrada y la salida que deseas. También, explicar lo que has intentado hasta ahora.  A tu pregunta actual, la respuesta es un simple: **si se puede**

Comment: ¿No están las tablas relacionadas entre sí? ¿Por qué usas `UNION`?

Comment: La clausula UNION es simplemente para unir dos consultas que listen la misma estructura para que se pueda dar la union bajo una misma cantidad de columnas y tipo de datos. Es completamente indiferente si se usa JOIN, GROUP BY, HAVING, etc...